# Python: Is it possible to make a tkinter program on top of all windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

is there any way to make a tkinter program on top of all windows? Like switching to a new window will not minimize or put the tkinter program back, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You just need to set the window manager attribute `topmost`:

```
mywindow.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
```